# Sliding a view Partially in a layout

Tags: android

I have a two views in a layout.On the click of a button in view 1 the second view must be visible and view 1 must be dragged in(Though not completely).I am sorry if havent been clear.To simplify things i am attaching some images.[image]

When i click on Button 2; View 1 becomes visible(View in white) and should occupy about 85 % of the screen and only a portion of the blue ball should be visible on the screen.What i have done so far is I have given weight to view 1 as 0.2 and to view 2 as 0.80.And view 1 as gone .On the button click(Button 2) i have made view 1 as visible.This works ok but i want only portion of the blue ball be visible on screen however the blue ball appears sqeezed instead of only part of the ball be visible.Can some one tell me what am i doing wrong in this?Or is there some other approach to do this?Thanks in advance If some one could help me in this!!!

My xml file is as follows :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bbb"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"

               >
          <include
                android:id="@+id/background_template_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/menuitems"
           />


    </LinearLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="0.1"
   >

   <include
        android:id="@+id/background_template_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/template_top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

     </include>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/parent_middle_botom"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/background_template_top"
       >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_strip_med"
    android:layout_below="@+id/background_template_top"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome,"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
          android:singleLine="true"
        >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Joyson"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        >
    </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

     <include
        android:id="@+id/background_template_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/template_bottom"
       android:layout_below="@+id/middle"
       >
      </include>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_sm_device"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        />

          <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/details"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
         >
         <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:src="@drawable/btn_on_small" />

         <TextView
         android:id="@+id/currentbatch"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Current Batch :"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
           android:singleLine="true"
         />

         <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/dummy"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/btn_on_small" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/count"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/currentbatch"
             android:text="0"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             >
             </TextView>

    <TextView
             android:id="@+id/Transaction"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Transactions |"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/currentbatch"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:textSize="15sp"
               android:singleLine="true"
             >
             </TextView>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/value"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="$ 0.00"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Transaction"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/currentbatch"
             android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
             android:textSize="15sp"
               android:singleLine="true"
             >
             </TextView>


       </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:background="@drawable/welcome_bg_small"
         >
      </RelativeLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the file that i have included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:layout_marginTop="14dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/creditcard_functions"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/reporting"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Reporting"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
           android:paddingLeft="8dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           >
         </TextView>


       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/functions"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Functions"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
           android:paddingLeft="8dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
          >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sale"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/creditcard_functions"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sale_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saletext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >

            </TextView>


        </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/authorizeonly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sale"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/authorize_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/authorize_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>


     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Ticketonly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/authorizeonly"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ticketonly_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tickettext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/giftcardfunctions"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Ticketonly"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"

         >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/giftcardfunctionstext"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text=" Functions"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
           android:paddingLeft="8dp"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             >
             </TextView>

         </RelativeLayout>


         <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Redeem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/giftcardfunctions"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/redeeem_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/redeemtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>



         <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Activate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Redeem"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activate_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activatetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>


          <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Deactivate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Activate"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deactivate_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deactivatetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Sale"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Addvalue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Deactivate"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addvalue_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_value"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addvaluetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Value"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>



         <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/BalanceInquiry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Addvalue"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/balanceinquiry_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/balance_inquiry_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balanceinquirytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Balance Inquiry"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Transfer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BalanceInquiry"
        android:background="@drawable/med_black_strip"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/transfer_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/transfer_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transfertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Transfer"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
         </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Such interaction reminds me of **Sliding menu pattern** (http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html) If this is the case you could integrate some cool library like this one https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.

Comment: The prixing app(Sub link in the first link u mentioned) has exactly the same UI i am looking to create.

Comment: I added my answer below. If you think it fits your need please mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get such an interaction using one of the **[Sliding Menu](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html)** pattern implementations out there. One of the most used has been implemented by Jeremy Feinstein and you can grab it on github here: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

It's dead simple to use and you can use it both in xml or in code. Look at the [readme](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/README.md) page on github for further informations on setup.

You can even find a sample eclipse project [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/example). It will help you get your hands dirty with the code.